# Grunt serve inside the Cordova App, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, gruntjs

I would like to use grunt serve command to serve my Angular/Cordova App from www directory.

I installed Grunt but if im tryed to use Grunt serve i got:

`A valid Gruntfile could not be found`.

So i tried to Grunfile.js from another project but i got a lot of errors.

I cannot use Yeoman in this case, because project is quite large and under git controll.

I would like just simple serve content of the www foler into browser.

What should to contain gruntfile.js for this?

Thanls for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run

```
$> python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

inside your www directory ?

If you really insist using grunt, checkout the [Getting Started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) documentation.

But if you decide to use a tool like that, consider using [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) instead!